# setting the readonly value in the html table for a specific line at the start of the form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I try to set readonly fields for specific lines where "sth" is set in select box

the code is executed when the page is loaded / at the start of the form

i tried:

.js file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


      $(".ecp-row").each(function () {

            var start = $(this).find(".start");
            var end = $(this).find(".end");
            var hours = $(this).find(".gethours");
            var selectboxlist = $(this).find(".selectboxlist").eq(0).val();

            if (selectboxlist === "sth") {



                alert("test");  // it works

                start.readOnly = true;  // it doesnt work
                end.readOnly = true;  // it doesnt work
                hours.readOnly = true;   // it doesnt work
                
                
            }
        });

  });
```

html

```
@for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < @ViewBag.sthelse; nr_rows++)
            {
 <tr class="ecp-row">
                    
      <td id="td3" >@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].a, new { @class = "start"})</td>
      <td id="td4" >@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].b, new { @class = "end" })</td>
      <td id="td5" >@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].c, new { @class = "gethours" })</td>
                    
      <td id="td6" >@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].sth, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(sth))), "  ", new { @class = "selectboxlist" })</td>

</tr>
}
```

Comment: You `start` and other variables in this case is a jquery Object and `start.readOnly = true` is a javascript way of setting the readOnly, so either use `start[0].readOnly = true` or `start.attr("readOnly","true")`

Comment: Also just a note `td3` and other ids in your `for` loop will be duplicated and an id should always remain unique.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, you problem is that you are trying to execute javascript code on a `jquery` object.

You can either use `start[0].readOnly = true;` or `start.attr("readOnly","true");`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ecp-row").each(function() {
    var start = $(this).find(".start");
    alert("test"); // it works
    //start[0].readOnly = true;
    start.attr("readOnly","true");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ecp-row">
      <td id="td3"><input class="start" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change readonly,you can use `prop` or `attr`:

prop:

```
var start = $(this).find(".start");
            start.prop("readonly", true);
```

attr:

```
var gethours = $(this).find(".gethours");
            gethours.attr("readonly", true);
```

And here's the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) between them.

demo:

```
    @for (int nr_rows = 0; nr_rows < @ViewBag.sthelse; nr_rows++)
{
    <tr class="ecp-row">
       
        start<td id="td3">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].a, new { @class = "start" })</td>
        end<td id="td4">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].b, new { @class = "end" })</td>
        gethours<td id="td5">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model7[nr_rows].c, new { @class = "gethours" })</td>
    </tr>
}
@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var start = $(this).find(".start");
            start.prop("readonly", true);
            var gethours = $(this).find(".gethours");
            gethours.attr("readonly", true);
        })
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

your are setting `readonly` property to `true` wrongly try instead jquery `attr()` method

```
 var start = $(this).find(".start");

 start.attr("readOnly","true");// set readonly to true
```